# Stop JSON.parse() from removing trailing zeros from a json string data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a JSON string as below :

```
<script>
var string = JSON.parse('{"items":[{"data":[5.1]}, {"values":[5.10]}, {"offer":[3.100]}, {"grandtotal":[121.9700]}]}');

$.each(string['items'][1]['values'], function(index, value) {
        console.log(value);
        var newval = value.toString();
        var abc = newval.split('.');
        console.log(abc[1]); //retuns 1 instead of 10
});
</script>
```

- In above Data Example 5.10, 5 is an unique-id and 10 is a quantity.

Comment: Then you have to quote them as strings, `3.100` will be `3.1` in just about any programming language, javascript included.

Comment: Or build a proper json, why implicitly encode the data

Comment: Why not just hold them as `{"values":[5, 10]}`?

Comment: Because User can select multiple packages So `{"values": [5.1, 100.2, 90.3]}`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use strings. Internally, in more or less any programming language, 5.1 and 5.100 have the same representation, whereas "5.1" and "5.100" will differ.

The JSON-data will then look like this:

```
var string = JSON.parse('{"items":[{"data":["5.1"]}, {"values":["5.10"]}, {"offer":["3.100"]}, {"grandtotal":["121.9700"]}]}');
```